# Mass convert latitude/longitude to decimal format as an excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, coordinates, formula

I have a spreadsheet that has latitude in column A and longitude in column B, in the format: 34° 3' 8.0460.

I want to be able to run a tool that when you press a button (after pasting data into columns A and B), will return columns C and D, which are the decimal values of A and B, respectively.

I’ve seen some functions that you can call individual cells to get results, but I need to be able to convert hundreds of cells in one click. Maybe include a “convert” button that runs the script?

Any ideas on a VBA code that could do the trick?

I’m fairly new to using coding.

Comment: You would use a For or While loop to process all cells.

Comment: How would I implement the looping into the second code at the bottom of the link? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213449/how-to-convert-degrees-minutes-seconds-angles-to-or-from-decimal-angle

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I’m not too familiar with looping, I understand the concept but not where to start or end the loops in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with a button; just let the paste operation trigger an event. Put this into the worksheet's private code sheet with right-click name tab, View Code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range, latlon As Variant
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("A:B"))
            If CBool(InStr(1, t.Value2, Chr(176))) And CBool(InStr(1, t.Value2, Chr(39))) And _
                     InStr(1, t.Value2, Chr(176)) < InStr(1, t.Value2, Chr(39)) Then
                latlon = Split(t.Value2, Chr(176))
                Debug.Print CInt(latlon(0))
                Debug.Print CInt(Split(latlon(1), Chr(39))(0))
                Debug.Print CDbl(Split(latlon(1), Chr(39))(1))
                t.Offset(0, 2) = CDbl(CInt(latlon(0)) + _
                                      CInt(Split(latlon(1), Chr(39))(0)) / 60 + _
                                      CDbl(Split(latlon(1), Chr(39))(1)) / 3600)
                t.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "0.00000000"
            End If
        Next t
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This will react to data pasted into columns A and/or B and convert to decimal lat/lons in columns C and D.

[image]

Comment: I just had a thought that you will have to adjust the maths if you typically use negative numbers for lons; e.g. `-85° 32' 4.3243`

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in detail in [this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/213449/how-to-convert-degrees-minutes-seconds-angles-to-or-from-decimal-angle)

To apply to all cells in a range, you could simply use:

```
Sub foo()
    With Sheet1.Range("C2:D" & Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=Convert_Decimal(RC[-2])"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I add this to the code from Microsoft? I want to be able to just run a tool after clicking some sort of “convert” button that will return all the values in columns C as D.

Comment: [Assign a macro to a Form or a Control button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283)